# makecert error: Can't access the key of the subject

Tags: windows, makecert

I have a powershell script that I want to run on 2 different stand-alone machines. On Windows 8.1 with the SDK installed, I issue the command:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=My Root Authority" -ss CA -sr CurrentUser ^
     -a sha1 -sky signature -cy authority -sv CA.pvk CA.cer
```

and I get back:

```
Error: Can't access the key of the subject ('CA.pvk')
Failed
```

CA.pvk gets created, but not CA.cer

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, Geoff

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849872.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Several confusing and unhelpful password prompts should pop up after running this command.

I got the same error message when I entered a different password in the second prompt to the one had I entered in the first.

> Entering the **same** password in both the **first** and **second**
>   pop-up screens got me past this.